# Nativescript android remove action bar

Tags: android, nativescript

I am trying to develop android app using Nativescript and try to remove Action Bar (top bar with "testns" title), but don't know how.
I am using code below but not working. Currently using tns v.1.3.0

`var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
    exports.pageLoaded = function(){
        var topmost = frameModule.topmost();
        topmost.android.showActionBar = false;
    };`

[image: Screenshot of the app]

Answer (score 63):

You can explicitly control the visibility of the **ActionBar** by setting the actionBarHidden property of the **Page**, look this:

```html
import {Page} from "ui/page";

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(page: Page) {
        page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the earlier versions the root was always a Frame, so by default there will be a Page. Now this is not working on the latest version of nativescript. With the latest version, you are allowed to define flexible root components and any number of frames (page-router-outlet) within your app. So there won't be a default Frame / Page created within app component. Page can be injected only into the components those are loaded inside the page-router-outlet.

Answer (score 41):

Finally I find the answer how to remove the actionbar. By adding `actionBarHidden = "true"` inside tag Page in xml file :

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded" actionBarHidden="true">
</Page>
```

Comment: is there another method? I don't use page tag

Comment: @Elgendy If you are using Angular, you use directive, I have posted an answer showing how to use it.

Comment: is there another method? I don't use page tag or angular

Answer (score 20):

This is the code for hidding the ActionBar in your NativeScript Angular TypeScript component.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(private page: Page) {
    }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: works for me in Android and iOS, but crashes when try to run the angular app in the browser

Answer (score 16):

`<page-router-outlet actionBarVisibility="never"></page-router-outlet>`

add [actionBarVisibility="never"] this in in your [app.component.html] file. Its working fine in my project.

Comment: This answer should be much higher up. With the newer versions of Nativescript using the page-router-outlet more this is easy, quick and clean. Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using angular and you don't use `page` in your html or you are using lazy loading of modules or you have multiple `page-router-outlet`, you take advantage of [directives](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive).

Create a new directive:

**hideActionBar.ts**

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from 'tns-core-modules/ui/page/page';

@Directive({
    selector: '[hideActionBar]'
})
export class HideActionBarDirective {
    constructor(private page: Page) {
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

and use this directive for the html where you want to hide the actionbar.

**SecondPage.html**

```
<GridLayout tkExampleTitle tkToggleNavButton rows="auto,*" hideActionBar>
 ...// other html goes here
</GridLayout>
```

P.S. Don't forget to declare it in NgModule as directives are [declarables](https://angular.io/api/core/Directive#declaring-directives). This is very useful for code sharing projects as you will be declaring it in ngmodule.tns.ts and it will not be compiled for web project.

```
declarations: [
 AppComponent,
 MyDirective
],
```

Comment: A very elegant solution taking advantage of Angular.

Comment: This answer is essential (and the only one that works) for [code-sharing](https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/code-sharing/intro) projects. Thank you!

Comment: not sure why all solutions above works for me - but the first row of the grid is off the screen

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to achieve this:

1. XML markup: just add 'actionBarHidden="true"' to your page markup.
   i.e`<Page loaded="pageLoaded" actionBarHidden="true">
   </Page>`
2. ```
   <StackLayout verticalAlignment="middle"> 
       <Button text="{{ abHidden ? 'Show ActionBar' : 'Hide ActionBar' }}" tap="onTap" textWrap="true" class="fa" />
   </StackLayout>
   ```

and in your .ts

```
export function onNavigatingTo(args: EventData) {
    const page = <Page>args.object;
    const vm = new Observable();
    vm.set("abHidden", value);
    page.bindingContext = vm;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
ActionBar {
  height: 0;
}
```

```html
<ActionBar [title]="appTitle">
</ActionBar>
```

Comment: It may help to add a paragraph or to explaining how the poster may use this code to solve his/her problem.  And possibly why the code s/he posted doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Page } from "@nativescript/core";

@Component({
  selector: "ns-items",
  templateUrl: "./items.component.html",
})
export class ItemsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private page: Page) { 
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
  }
}
```