# How to hide the android actionbar with angular2 and typescript?

Tags: javascript, android, typescript, nativescript

I have a simple html file:

```
<StackLayout orientation="vertical" actionBarHidden="true">
      <Image src="res://buy" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
</StackLayout>
```

But when i use:

```
<Page actionBarHidden="true">
  <StackLayout orientation="vertical">
      <Image src="res://buy" stretch="none" horizontalAlignment="center"></Image>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

It breaks the page.. 
The action bar is not hidden and there is a huge margin between content and action bar.

I use angular2 and typescript for my app.

What's my mistake?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can target the page property in your component JS, with something like this:

```
export class HomePage implements OnInit {
    page: Page;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.page = <Page>topmost().currentPage;
        this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

You'll alos need to import `import {topmost} from "ui/frame";` and `import {Page} from "ui/page";`.

That way you don't need the  tags (which are implicit in an Angular 2 component).

I hope that helps!

Also, just to follow up on Brad's comments about self-closing tags - you'll find that with Angular, explicit closing tags (as you are doing) work much better.

Comment: Thank you, but now i get the error property page does not exist on type HomePage( my class )

Comment: Thank you, can you explain me what page: Page does? And second, i get the error can not find topmost, but i'll try it with somthing else than topmost. :)

Comment: @olivier ahh, sorry - you need to have `import {Page} from "ui/page";` at the top of your component and `import {topmost} from "ui/frame";`

Answer (score 6):

There is an easier solution. Tested on Angular `4.1.0` and NativeScript `3.0.0`

```
import { Page } from "ui/page";

export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private page: Page) {
        page.actionBarHidden = true;
    }
}
```

You can control the visibility of the `ActionBar` from the constructor of your component.

StackOverflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39962992/2765346

Comment: Yes, this worked, however I don't understand why do we need to import another component to hide something...

Answer (score 1):

The property `actionBarHidden` only works on the `<Page>` component. Don't think you can apply it to a `<StackLayout>`. You also don't have to specify `orientation="vertical"` on a `<StackLayout>` it's vertical by default. Unless there is a specific use case you are trying to achieve that isn't mentioned here :)

https://docs.nativescript.org/ApiReference/ui/page/Page.html

Just another tip - you can self close `<Image />` no need for the `</Image>` tag.

Comment: Thank you! Can you explain me where i can hide the action bar?

Comment: You already have it on the `<Page>` component in the one snippet. That is the only place where that property works, it's in the documentation page in my first comment. So you cannot use it on `<StackLayout>`.

Comment: Ok, thanks, but i copied it from here: https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/blob/master/apps/action-bar-demo/pages/action-bar-hidden.xml

Comment: Well what you have isn't an exact copy, but that is the correct way to hide the ActionBar. If you need further clarification let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
import { Page } from "tns-core-modules/ui/page";

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {

   public constructor(private router: RouterExtensions, private page: Page) {
   
   }

   public ngOnInit() {
     this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
   }

}
```