# Multiple questions about Nativescript + Angular2 development

Tags: android, angular, nativescript

I have multiple questions about development that's I find very hard to find in forums and most of the time not being noticed on chat rooms:

- How do I receive parameter from a route?
  This one is very hard to find..
- How to remove Action Bar throughout the Android part of things, tried but failed:

  [Nativescript android remove action bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33381486/nativescript-android-remove-action-bar)
- How to center the text inside the label vertically, tried vertical-align: middle and vertical-align: middle but both

Please help. Thank you. :)

Comment: Please ask one question at a time and post some code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

In regard to your first question, you could review [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#route-parameters) angular article, where have been shown how to send parameters via angular router.

In case you want to hide the `ActionBar` you could set `startPageActionBarHidden` property to `true` in your `main.ts` For example:

`main.ts`

```
import {nativeScriptBootstrap} from "nativescript-angular/application";
import {AppComponent} from "./app.component";
import { NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS } from "nativescript-angular/router";

nativeScriptBootstrap(AppComponent,[NS_ROUTER_PROVIDERS],{ startPageActionBarHidden: true });
```

About your last question, you could use `vertical-align` for the Label in your `css` file.

`app.css`

```
label{
    vertical-align: center;
}
```

I hope this is applicable for you. However it would help if you could give me more info about your problem.